# Custom DataGridView row-pairing

Tags: c#, datagridview, custom-controls

I am designing a windows application (C#). I have two datagridviews side by side. I want to allow user to match any single row on the left grid to single row on the right grid. I want that the user should be allowed to match as n number of single rows on the left to that many single rows on the right on one-to-one basis. How do I do it?

What I mean is, I can match 3rd row on the left with 5th row on the right (to form a pair), then match the 4th row on the left to match may 1st row on the right, and so on to form maybe 20 or 30 pairs. But after that hit submit button only once to indicate one batch of job is over.

Anybody any ideas.

Comment: What are you wanting to match on. If you don't know, then I would suggest some kind of ID column(hidden) so you can quickly match the rows you want. Could you explain more; is data different from each grid... We need details and some code you have tried so we can better understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi, I am essentially matching two transactions accounts. like gird 1 will have amount, date/time & accnt number. Second grid will also have similar columns. Only by viewing each entry someone can match two entries (on each side). Now to increase the productivity, I have to allow many such single entries on the left grid to be matched to many such entries on the right grid. There lies the problem.How to know which entry on the left is being matched to which one on the right?